# Excel TREND() input arrays made from several ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is somehow possible to create inputs (`known_y` a `known_x`)  for [`TREND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/trend-function-e2f135f0-8827-4096-9873-9a7cf7b51ef1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function, when cells are not in single range?

### Example:

I want to check middle value (B3) against `TREND` result (without re-arranging the table)

```
+---+----+----+
|   | A  | B  |
+---+----+----+
| 1 | X  | Y  |
| 2 | 0  | 0  |
| 3 | 5  | 5  |
| 4 | 10 | 10 |
+---+----+----+
```

It means that `known_y` are {B2;B4}, `known_x` {A2;A4}.

So I tried to create matrix for `TREND` input arrays: `=TREND({B2;B4},{A2;A4};A5)` but this is not recognized as proper function. It seems references are not allowed in manually made matrixes (simple `={A1;A2}` doesn't work neither).

Is there some trick how to achieve desired behavior without creating a new table where `TREND` input data will be in one range?

**THIS IS END OF ORIGINAL QUESTION**

---

*Added 2020-04-24 12:48*

**Not working (attempt) solution with nested matrix formulas**

I also tried workaround to create "range" from cells which are not neighbors. For clarity named ranges (columns) are used here (column heading = Name of the range).

```
Given data
+----+----+  +-----+  +-----+
| x  | y  |  | seq |  | mask|
+----+----+  +-----+  +-----+
|  0 |  0 |  |   1 |  |   3 |
|  5 |  5 |  |   2 |  |   1 |
| 10 | 10 |  |   3 |  +-----+
| 15 | 15 |  |   4 |  
| 20 | 20 |  |   5 |  
+----+----+  +-----+
```

Then using matrix formulas for creating "known" arrays:

```
+---------+---------+     |   
| known_x | known_y |     |   known_x  {=INDEX(x,MATCH(mask,seq,0))}
+---------+---------+     |   known_Y  {=INDEX(y,MATCH(mask,seq,0))}
|      10 |      10 |     |   
|       0 |       0 |     |   
+---------+---------+     |
```

And finally put these in `TREND` function. `=TREND(known_y,known_x,5)`
But it returns `10` - because `known_y`, `known_x` are not treated as matrices - only the first cell is taken into the computation.

Tried also:

```
{=TREND(INDEX(y,MATCH(mask,seq,0)),INDEX(x,MATCH(mask,seq,0)),5)}
```

But same behavior (result = `10`).

Thank you for advice and sorry for my English.

Formulas are translated to English using [Excel Translator](https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=TREND(INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},{2,4}))),INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},{2,4}))),A5)
```

Depending on ones version it may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Where `{2,4}` are the rows desired. Others can be added.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works! But I can't figure out what `N(IF({1},{2,4}))` does. It returns `{2,4}`, but when I tried to replace it with `{2,4},` it returns `#REF!` error. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481808) `{1}` in `IF` means "always `True`", so it always returns `{2,4}`. For some reason it has to be in `{}` because answer is a matrix. N function is necessary here (despite the [Excel help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/n-function-a624cad1-3635-4208-b54a-29733d1278c9)), because it converts to "number matrix". Is it right?

Comment: That is correct we need to "trick" the index into accepting the array.  It is a loop hole that Microsoft fixed with the advent of Dynamic Array formulas.  With a subscription to Office 365 one gets the Dynamic Array formula and we no longer need this "trick" to pass an array to INDEX.